# Error: Failed to connect while Publishing Click Once Application Wpf

Tags: wpf, clickonce

[image]I got an error while publishing my WPF application. I am publishing on the desktop
and the location of the installation folder and the publish folder is the same. \
Error says---

> Error 1   Failed to connect to
>   '\localhost\Users\Administrator\Desktop\deploy\' with the following
>   error: Unable to create the Web site
>   '\localhost\Users\Administrator\Desktop\deploy'.  The path
>   '\localhost\Users\Administrator\Desktop\deploy' does not exist or you
>   do not have access. The specified path is invalid.

Comment: do you really have any folder at that location ?

Comment: yes i created a folder on desktop as deploy....

Comment: it is really difficult to understand like this please provide some code

Comment: I wouldn't expect \localhost\ to mean the C:/ drive.

Comment: when i paste the path of that folder it automatically set as the localhost,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have to change the path from local host to c:/
 then it successfully build.