# ClickOnce running an error when publishing Application

Tags: vb.net, clickonce, publish

whenever I try to publish my application and it gives me this error:

Failed to connect to '\localhost\users\Dylan Garcia\Desktop\8.2.1_File\' with the following error: unable to create the Web site '\localhost\users\Dylan Garcia\Desktop\8.2.1_File\'. The path '\localhost\users\Dylan Garcia\Desktop\8.2.1_File\' does not exist or you do not have access. The specified path is invalid.

how could i resolve this issue?

Comment: Similar question is already answered. please use this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31782139/error-failed-to-connect-while-publishing-click-once-application-wpf

Answer (score 0):

Hope you have already fixed this error.

First make sure that you have created the folder `8.2.1_File` on your desktop, then try either one of the following

```
\\\localhost\users\Dylan Garcia\Desktop\8.2.1_File\
```

or

```
C:\users\Dylan Garcia\Desktop\8.2.1_File\
```